# CSS - Left align the last row of images in a centered div

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have multiple rows of images that I am centering on a page.  The code below does this and if the user resizes their browser, the images stay centered.  I need the last line of images to be left aligned though.  How can I do this?

```
<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style> 
#outer
{ 
width: 100%; 
text-align: center; 
}
#inner
{ 
display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br /><br />
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner">
<img id="0" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="1" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="2" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="3" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="4" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="5" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="6" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="7" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="8" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="9" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="10" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="11" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="12" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="13" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="14" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="15" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="16" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="17" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="18" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
<img id="19" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/slider/judaism.stackexchange.com.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" /> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

~ M

Answer (score 1):

you may try

```
#12{
  float: left;
}
```

which keeps items to left.

Comment: When I do that, only the one image goes to the left and it doesn't remain centered with the images on the first row.

Comment: I would like all of the images on the last row to be left aligned but the left edge of the image needs to align with the row above.

Comment: you mean you want to align all images inside `<div id="inner">` ?

Comment: See how the blocks are centered on this page and the last line is left aligned in regards to all the blocks, that is what I am trying to do: http://stackexchange.com/sites#