# How to keep wrapped flex-items the same width as the elements on the previous row?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a `<ul>` that is a flex-box and a bunch of `<li>`s in it which are the flex-items.

I am trying to get the `<li>` to have a flexible width, that stays between two sizes using min-width and max-width. It works great as long as they are on the same line. However, when they wrap, the `<li>` s on the new line use as much space as they can. Which means they are small on the first line, and big on the second line when there are just a few of them.

Is there a way to tell flexbox to keep the items the width after wrapping, while keeping the flexible width?

**wrapping demo:**

[image]

My code looks like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/250/250">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```sass
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

  li {
    min-width: 40px;
    max-width: 100px;
    flex: 1 0 0;
  }
```

**[Here's a live example on codepen with some extra comments](http://codepen.io/midu/pen/gahFu)**, resize your window to see it wrap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex-box: Align last row to grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid)

Comment: well... yes and no. The recommendation seems to be to use CSS columns but that does not really help either since you can't have a variable number of columns ([that I know of](http://codepen.io/midu/pen/qHuDB).) Maybe it's just not possible to have flexible width elements that wrap but stay the same width.

Comment: Yes, you can have variable columns:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/CcGlE

Comment: At the moment, this is not possible with a flexbox. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/28076932/923032

Comment: And how did you post that?

Comment: I thought to myself "surely it's not that hard", then spent an hour playing with your codepen. Now I wish I'd read @gummbahla's comment first.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

## TL;DR

This is not something I'd call a *solution* per se, but it's a rather elegant workaround that only uses media queries, and more importantly *no JavaScript*!

### Mixin (SCSS):

```
@mixin flex-wrap-fix($flex-basis, $max-viewport-width: 2000px) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: $flex-basis;
  max-width: 100%;

  $multiplier: 1;
  $current-width: 0px;

  @while $current-width < $max-viewport-width {
    $current-width: $current-width + $flex-basis;
    $multiplier: $multiplier + 1;

    @media(min-width: $flex-basis * $multiplier) {
      max-width: percentage(1/$multiplier);
    }
  }
}
```

### Usage:

Apply the mixin to your flex item:

```
.flex-item {
  @include flex-wrap-fix(100px)
}
```

### Update:

The above mixin should do the trick, as long as you your flex container width matches your viewport size, as is the case in OP's example. Media queries won't help you otherwise, because they're always based on the viewport width. However, you could use the [`css-element-queries`](https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries) library and its element queries instead of browser media queries. Here's a mixin that you can apply to the flex *container*:

```
@mixin flex-container-wrap-items($flex-basis, $max-expected-width: 2000px) {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  > * {
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: $flex-basis;
  }

  $multiplier: 1;
  $current-width: 0px;

  @while $current-width < $max-expected-width {
    $current-width: $current-width + $flex-basis;
    $multiplier: $multiplier + 1;

    &[min-width~="#{$flex-basis * $multiplier}"] > * {
      max-width: percentage(1/$multiplier);
    }
  }
}
```

---

## Explanation:

Let's say, as per the OP's example, we want each item to have a maximum width of `100px`, so we know that for a browser width of `100px` we can fit one item per row, and so on:

```
| Viewport Width | Max Item Count Per Row | Item Width (min-max) |
|----------------|------------------------|----------------------|
| <= 100         | 1                      | 0px - 100px          |
| <= 200         | 2                      | 50px - 100px         |
| <= 300         | 3                      | 50px - 100px         |
| <= 400         | 4                      | 50px - 100px         |
| <= 500         | 5                      | 50px - 100px         |
| <= 600         | 6                      | 50px - 100px         |
```

We can write media queries to create the following rules:

```
| Viewport Width | Max Item Count Per Row | Item Max Width | Calculation |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| <= 100px       | 1                      | 100%           | (100/1)     |
| <= 200px       | 2                      | 50%            | (100/2)     |
| <= 300px       | 3                      | 33.33333%      | (100/3)     |
| <= 400px       | 4                      | 25%            | (100/4)     |
| <= 500px       | 5                      | 20%            | (100/5)     |
| <= 600px       | 6                      | 16.66666%      | (100/6)     |
```

Like this:

```
li {
  flex: 1 0 0
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media(min-width: 200px) {
  li { max-width: 50%; }
}

@media(min-width: 300px) {
  li { max-width: 33.33333%; }
}

@media(min-width: 400px) {
  li { max-width: 25%; }
}

@media(min-width: 500px) {
  li { max-width: 20%; }
}

@media(min-width: 600px) {
  li { max-width: 16.66666%; }
}
```

Of course, that's repetitive, but most likely you're using some sort of preprocessor, which can take care of the repetitiveness for you.  That's precisely what the mixin in the above **TL;DR** section does.

All we have to do now is to specify `100px` as our `flex-basis`, and *optionally* the maximum browser window width (defaults to `2000px`) to create the media queries for:

```
@include flex-wrap-fix(100px)
```

## Example

Finally, a forked version of the original CodePen example with the desired output, using the above mixin:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNVzoJ

[image: demo of the solution]

Answer (score 43):

### Alternative - grid

It's not the answer to what you want, but it nice to use:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(70px, 1fr));
```

https://codepen.io/omergal/pen/povzJrz

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(70px, 1fr));
}

li {
  min-width: 40px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  background-color: tomato;
}

li {
  margin: 0.5em;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
figure,
img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/250/250">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/101/101">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/201/201">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/80/80">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/111/111">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/40/40">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/110/110">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/75/75">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/89/89">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/32/32">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/61/61">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/320/320">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: There's an entire page on MDN, [Mastering Wrapping of Flex Items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items#single-dimensional_layout_explained), dedicated to the wrapping of flex items. 

"There is no method in flexbox to tell items in one row to line up with items in the row above — each flex line acts like a new flex container. ...If you want layout in two dimensions then you probably want Grid Layout."

Answer (score 13):

I have been experimenting with your CodePen and I set
`flex: 0 1 10%`

Of course you can set the flex-basis whatever you want, I just wanted to prove the point, that if you set flex basis and allow it to shrink, it will behave much nicer in this case.

I think this is what you needed. Here's the preview:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwqNEZ

Answer (score 5):

I think I got it...but it's hacky. The result is the 14 images each scaling from 100px wide down to 40px, even on multiple rows.

[image: From 107px to 40px Width]

- Added a duplicate set of the 14 original `<li>`s and added them to the flex `<ul>`.
- Next, the second set was rendered invisible:

  ```
  li:nth-of-type(n + 15) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  ```
- In order to maintain uniform flexibility the following changes to each `<li>`:

  ```
  li {
    min-width: 40px;
    max-width: 10%;
    flex: 1 0 100px;
  }
  ```

Please review the **[CodePen](http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/YqEXaX)**

and/or the **Snippet** in Full Page mode.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 258px;
}
li {
  min-width: 40px;
  max-width: 10%;
  flex: 1 0 100px;
}
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  background-color: tomato;
}
li {
  margin: 0.5em;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
li img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
li figure,
li img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li:nth-of-type(n + 15) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/250/250">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/101/101">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/201/201">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/80/80">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/111/111">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/40/40">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/110/110">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/75/75">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/89/89">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/32/32">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/61/61">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/320/320">
    </figure>
  </li>



  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/250/250">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/101/101">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/201/201">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/80/80">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/111/111">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/40/40">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/110/110">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/75/75">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/89/89">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/32/32">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/61/61">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/320/320">
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `min-width` and `max-width` as percentages has allowed all images to stay the same width when they break onto the next line. It is not ideal, but closer to what you are after?

```css
li {
  min-width: 15%;
  max-width: 15%;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Stylus you can use this mixin: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Epjwjq

```
   flex-wrap-fix($basis, $max) {
     flex-grow: 1
     flex-basis: $basis
     max-width: 100%

     $multiplier = ceil($max / $basis)

     for i in (1..$multiplier) {
       @media(min-width: ($basis * i)) {
         max-width: percentage(1/i)
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking to solve the same problem for a flex box I have. I've since realised that this is now much easier with `display: grid` as detailed [here](https://medium.com/deemaze-software/css-grid-responsive-layouts-and-components-eee1badd5a2f) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46099319/5560171).

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of flexbox. The best thing you can do is set a max-width which the wrapping (growing) item will respect. You need CSS Grid for this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect but worth try. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKmXpV

The changes are

```
li
  width: 7.1428%
  flex: 0 0 auto

figure
  margin: 0 auto
  background-color: darkgreen
  min-width: 40px
  max-width: 100px
```

- changed li flex to "0 0 auto" and the li width to a percentage based on
  the number of lis.
- moved the min and max widths from the li to the figure
- moved the green background to the figure and centered the figures in
  the lis

Answer (score 0):

Its not working very well, but you can achieve something in this direction with columns.

```
column-gap: 10px;
column-width: 150px;
```

https://codepen.io/hobbeshunter/pen/OgByNX

Comment: Got it, thanks. Why did you say it's not working very well? Are you referring to browser/feature support?

Comment: Well it's not exactly what midu wanted as it reorders the elements in columns and not rows.

Comment: I noticed that, very strange.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not ideal, as it leans on JQuery: http://codepen.io/BigWillie/pen/WwyEXX

CSS

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  min-width: 40px;
  max-width: 100px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var eqRowFlexItem = function(elem) {
    var w;
    var $elem = $(elem);
    // Clear out max-width on elements
    $elem.css('max-width', '');
    w = $(elem).eq(0).width();
    $(elem).css('max-width', w);
}

eqRowFlexItem('li');

$(window).resize(function() {
    eqRowFlexItem('li');
});
```

I'm not entirely sure if it answers the problem. I found this post, as the title matched the problem I was having. I was after an effect whereby I would have a greater number of elements per row on larger screens - and fewer elements per row on smaller screens. In both cases, these elements also needed to scale to fit... across devices.

However, those stray elements on the last row would always expand to fill the remaining space.

The JQuery gets the width of the first element - and applies it as a max-width to every element. The OP wanted the blocks to fall within a min-width / max-width rage. Setting the max-width in CSS seems to work. We clear the max-width off the element, so it defaults to the max-width in the CSS... then gets the actual width.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so I used a very tiny bit of Jquery to control the width of the boxes and make them all the same width even once they wrap.

My demo is on CodePen [Flex wrap, with equal width on new row](https://codepen.io/HairyT/pen/yMxzrR)

```js
function resize(){
  var colWidth;
  var screen = $(window).width(); 
  
  if(screen < 576){
    colWidth = Math.round(screen / 2) - 31;
    $(".item").width(colWidth);
  } 
  if(screen > 575 && screen < 768){
    colWidth = Math.round(screen / 3) - 31;
    $(".item").width(colWidth);
  } 
  else if (screen > 767 && screen < 992){
      colWidth = Math.round(screen / 4) -31;
      $(".item").width(colWidth);
  }
  else if (screen > 991 ){
      colWidth = Math.round(screen / 6) -31;
      $(".item").width(colWidth);
  }
}
  
window.onresize = function() {
  resize();
}

resize();
```

```css
html,
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  background-color:#ddd;
}

.wrap    { 
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}  

.item {
  background: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  margin:0 15px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="flex-container wrap">
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item">3</li>
  <li class="item">4</li>
  <li class="item">5</li>
  <li class="item">6</li>
  <li class="item">7</li>
  <li class="item">8</li>
  <li class="item">9</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the layout is fixed, you could simply add hidden items and toggle their visibility using css breakpoints for the pixels where wrapping happens.

for example, in the following scenario *.columned-list* has 3 *.columned-list-item* elements, and for the pixels within which the 3rd .columned-list-item element wraps to the next row, I just make the 4th *.columned-list-item* element *.hidden-item* - which is normally invisible - visible :

```
.columned-list {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin-left: 35px;


            justify-content: flex-start;



            .hidden-item {
                display: none !important;

                @media only screen and (max-width: 1375px) {
                    flex: 1 0 auto !important;
                    min-width: 410px !important;
                    width: 30% !important;
                    margin: 0 37px 37px 0 !important;
                    max-width: 100% !important;
                    display: flex !important;
                    background-color: #fff !important;
                }

                @media only screen and (max-width: 928px) {
                    display: none !important;
                }
            }

            .columned-list-item {
                flex: 1 0 auto;
                min-width: 410px;
                min-height: 1px !important; // <3 IE.
                width: 30%;
                margin: 0 37px 37px 0;
                max-width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                color: #676562;
                background-color: #f2f3f5;

                a:nth-of-type(1) {
                    position: relative;
                    min-height: 84px;
                    width: 100%;

                    img {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: auto;
                    }

                    div {
                        min-height: 88px;
                        max-width: 203px;
                        padding: 0 15px;
                        top: 50%;
                        transform: translateY(-50%);
                        position: absolute;
                        display: flex;
                        justify-content: center;
                        align-items: center;

                        background-color: #fff;
                        opacity: 0.6;
                        span {
                            height: 55px;
                            font-family: 'Trade Gothic Next LT W04 Rg', sans-serif;
                            font-size: 28px;
                            font-weight: bold;
                            font-stretch: normal;
                            font-style: normal;
                            line-height: 1;
                            letter-spacing: 0.7px;
                            text-align: left;
                            color: #676562;
                        }

                    }

                }

                a:nth-of-type(2) {

                    padding: 10px 35px;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    min-height: 161px;
                    max-width: 390px;

                    strong {
                        font-family: 'Trade Gothic Next LT W04 Bold', sans-serif;
                        font-weight: bold;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                    span {

                        font-family: 'Trade Gothic Next LT W04 Light', sans-serif;
                        font-size: 15px;
                        font-weight: normal;
                        font-stretch: normal;
                        font-style: normal;
                        line-height: 1.4;
                        letter-spacing: normal;
                        text-align: center;
                        color: #676562;

                    }
                }

                .buttons-block {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: space-between;
                    align-items: center;
                    width: 298px;
                    max-width: 100%;
                    margin: 10px 0 23px 0;

                    .button-a {
                        width: 114px;
                        height: 22px;
                        min-height: 1px;
                        box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
                        background-color: #f28d4e;
                        display: flex;
                        justify-content: center;
                        align-items: center;

                        span {
                            font-family: 'Trade Gothic Next LT W04 Rg', sans-serif;
                            font-size: 15px;
                            font-weight: bold;
                            font-stretch: normal;
                            font-style: normal;
                            line-height: 1.4;
                            letter-spacing: normal;
                            text-align: center;
                            color: #ffffff;
                        }
                    }

                    .button-b {
                        margin-bottom: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                    }

                }

                @media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
                    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
                }
                @media only screen and (max-width: 410px) {

                    min-width: auto;
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
                display: flex !important;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                margin-left: 0;
                padding-top: 10px;
            }


        }
```

Answer (score -1):

use `max-width: 40px` not `max-width: 100px`

Comment: This does not solve the problem @midu is having which is to try and keep the flexible widths of both `40px` and `100px`.