# Have flex parent be width of its content and prevent excess white space

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, whitespace

I have this flexbox which holds a few menu items. When the screen width goes down I need these items to wrap. when the items wrap the container keeps a certain width to fit the wrapped items which leaves excess white space in my menu which I don't need. How do I force the flexbox to always be the width of the content.

Here's a screenshot of the menu with the excess space on the left

[image: flexbox-menu]

All the space on the left of 'Inspiratie' must be removed. Keep in mind This menu is placed in a flexbox with a searchbox that adjusts its width with the screen till a minimum width of 30%. If you need any code of the other elements I'm happy to provide.

This is the SCSS I have for the menu:

```
#menu-top-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    row-gap: 0.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Simply, don't use justify-content: flex-end. Instead use justify-content:space-between or space-around or space evenly.

Comment: Thing is, that isn't the styling I want. I need every wrapped list item to start on the right

Comment: So you want items start from right on large screen. And won lower screen it should take full width and don't go to next line. Right?

Comment: If you explain correctly, I will make sure to give you your desired result. Currently I am little confused.

Comment: So if you look at the image, the way the elements wrap right now is perfect. It's that excess purple white space on the left that I dont't want. I just want that the width of the container to always be the width of the elements. So if an element gets wrapped, it must become as wide as the upper row of elements.

Comment: So, currently the wrapping is right in the image. Only the left space is issue. So, why are you not using justify-content: space-between or space-around or space-evenly??

Answer (score 2):

Web pages uses the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) to display elements. Basically, an element could occup full screen width or share screen space with others elements.
When you set the `#menu-top-menu` to have the `justify-content: flex-end;` you are telling the element to squeeze the content at the end of the free space, which means that if the element occup full screen width, the content should be squeezed to the right of the screen.

To make the element fit the width to the wrapped items you could use the property `width: fit-content`, however, this would make the element be aligned to the start, not the end of the page as you can see on these images:

- [before fit-content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqWBU.png)
- [after fit-content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxJbF.png)

You could make the parent element of `#menu-top-menu` have the `display: flex` too but having the `justify-content: flex-end` instead of the current element. [image: Here is the example].

#### Edit

Based on the message, I think you need a more complex solution to do this. This [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274338/how-to-keep-wrapped-flex-items-the-same-width-as-the-elements-on-the-previous-ro) might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This indeed makes the elements aligned to the left which isn't what i'm looking for. the menu-top-menu is a <ul> with <li>'s. This <ul> is wrapped by a <nav class="top-nav">

```
<nav class="top-nav">
    <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="menu">
...
    </ul>
</nav>

also when using the fit-content and having it aligned to the left, it has excess whitespace on the right side so i'm faced with the same problem again...

Comment: I've linked another answer that I think might help you, check it out :)