# Css Container Div Size

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue getting a DIV to resize to fit the content when it forces its child divs to move down.

What I'm trying to do in the sample is have the container div's width to that of the children so that I can have the container centered on the page.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
#container {
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    /* for ie6/7: */
    *display: inline;
}
.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

When you look at the example the container is expanding to 100% while leaving space between right most child and the container.
[image: Div Issue Example]
http://jsfiddle.net/rjY7F/594/

Comment: You can add either a max-width or a width: % to the container.

Comment: The problem with that is I need the div to be able to respond to the page size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center grid of inline-block elements in div, but last row is aligned with left edge of grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527104/center-grid-of-inline-block-elements-in-div-but-last-row-is-aligned-with-left-e)

Answer (score 1):

```
#container {display:table;}
.box {display:table-cell; float:none; vertical-align:top;}
```

Then set the width of the .box style to something like 100px, and set the width of #container to the combined width.

Comment: This almost works. The float:none is causing everything to stay on the same row instead of moving down into the next row. Removing the float none cause it to have to same problem it had before.

Comment: What more is needed then?

Comment: I need the items to be able to move to the next row of different monitors. When ever the are more items on the first row that will fit and it wraps the items down it's leaving the white space between the right side of the top most row and the div.

Comment: Put margin:0px; on the images. To wrap the images, set a specific width smaller than the combined width of the images.

Answer (score 1):

I would use display table on the container, add a width 100% to keep the layout size. Use display table-cell on the box,

here is the code :

```
#container {
text-align: left;
border: 1px solid red;
display: table;
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:100%;
}
.box {
display:table-cell;
height:100px;
border:1px solid blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rjY7F/603/

Answer (score 1):

> [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) can be helpful in this scenario

To make a flexbox environment you must start by setting the parent element (in your case `container`) to `display:flex`.

For the flex-items you can just set the `min-width`  but I suggest you also look into all the awesome features flexbox offers...